# How to save integers and decimals into each list using list comprehensions?

Tags: python

How to save integers and decimals into each list using list comprehensions?

my list code

```
 arr = [1.13, 22.23, 333.33, 44.43, 555.53, 66.63]
```

For example, the values listed below.

I want to separate 1.13 values into integers, decimals.

Input has exception handling.

```
if input 1.03 -> output [1,03] and input 1.3 -> output [1,3]
```

**update post**

My goals OutPut

**Generate a [integer, decimal] paired list (with letters, numbers).**

```
Ex) [['1', '13'], ['22', '23'], ['333', '33'], ['44', '43’],['555', '53'], ['66', '63’]]


 [[1,13], [22,23], [333,33], [44,43], [555,53], [66,63]]
```

Comment: `[[int(x) for x in str(i).split('.')] for i in arr]`

Comment: You are a genius.

Please ask us questions. I'll take it
Thank you so much.

Comment: What if the input contains `1.03` and `1.3`? They'll both end up being `[1,3]` in the result.

Comment: @Barmar  oh sorry, post update. `if input 1.03 -> [1,03] , and input 1.3 -> [1,3]`

Comment: `[1, 03]` is the same as `[1, 3]`. Leading zeroes don't have any significance in numbers.

Comment: If you need `03` in the result it will need to be a list of strings, not a list of integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr = [1.13, 22.23, 333.33, 44.43, 555.53, 66.63]
```

Via list comprehension:

```
arr_new = [[str(num).split(".")[0], str(num).split(".")[1]] for num in arr]
```

The same operation via a `for` loop:

```
arr_new = []
for num in arr:
    num_parts = str(num).split(".")
    int_part = num_parts[0]
    dec_part = num_parts[1]
    arr_new.append([int_part, dec_part])
```

Comment: You must use list comprehensions, not use for loop.

Comment: @Python-97 The translation to list comprehensions is trivial.

Comment: @Python-97 I've added a snippet that does the same via list comprehension to my answer. Is this what you've been looking for?

Comment: What happens if the number is an `int`, won't it fail when it tries to get `[1]` from the split?

Comment: @BenY Yes, applying this to `int`s will throw an `IndexError`. From the initial post, however, I take that OP is only concerned with "splitting" `float`s (cf. "I want to separate 1.13 values into integers, decimals.").

Answer (score -1):

`arr_new = [[round(w), str(round(f, 2))[2:]] for w, f in [divmod(n, 1) for n in arr]]`

Except that I'm not sure I understand how you'd want to lose the place info by truncating the number, so i kept the fractional part as a string.